# Struts validation error

Tags: java, xml, validation, maven, configuration-files

I am using struts validation for my project.I use maven dependency.I add plug-in for struts validation in struts-config.xml file.

When I add `value='/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml'`, it displays an error:

```
cannot resolve symbol '/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml'
```

I have no idea about this error. When I run my project i get `invocationtarget exception`.

I am not sure whether the exception occurs due to this or any other problem. I've searched a lot to find a solution but I failed. Below is the code i add in my config file. Please help to solve this:

```
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorPlugIn">
        <set-property property="pathnames"
            value="/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml,/WEB-INF/conf/validation.xml" />
    </plug-in>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download validator-rules.xml fromt his location http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.struts/struts-core/1.3.9/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml and add in to your WEB_INF location.
2. Download struts-core.jar and add this jar file to your project.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and it worked. When I included '/org/apache/struts/validator/validator-rules.xml' in the value path it shows an error. Anyway the problem is solved.

Comment: Maven dependency for struts core is                        <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
 <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
 <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>. Maybe helpful to anyone.